# gameObject Transform in DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use the following script to copy the transform of a gameObject.

```
public Transform alignment;

void Update()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);

    transform.position = new Vector3(alignment.position.x, alignment.position.y, alignment.position.z);
    float y = alignment.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;
    float x = alignment.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x;
    float z = alignment.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z;
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

I want to acces this transform in other scenes (apply it to gameObjects).
How can I reach the transforms, that are in DontDestroyOnLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use DontDestroyOnLoad in your update function. Use it in your Start or Awake funciton.

Secondly you can access your Non-Destroyed object like you would any other object.
Only differences between the two is that the Non-Destroyed stays in the scene when changing scenes.

Here are some ways to access it:

```
var obj = GameObject.Find("My Non Destroyed Object Name");
```

Or my personal favorite, if the object is used for scoring or settings I'll create a new gameobject and add the following script to it:

```
public class GameManager : MonoDevelop {

    /* These are all script on the same gameobject that is not being destroyed */
    public static Settings settings;
    public static PlayerMananger playerMananger;
    public static UIManager uiManager;
    
    
    void Start() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameobject);
        
        // Get the components
        settings = GetComponent<Settings>();
        playerMananger = GetComponent<PlayerMananger>();
        uiManager = GetComponent<UIManager>();
    }   
}
```

Now I can create a script from anywhere and I can access all these Manager and setting files simply using:

```
var settings = GameManager.settings;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It already helped me a lot to understand what's going on.
But I start to understand, that this might not be what I am looking for..

To clarify - this is what I am thinking about:
I have a gameObject, and it changes its transform on Playtime. I want the equivalent gameObjects in the other scenes to match this new transform. I can't use DontDestroyOnLoad in this case, because the gameObjects should be different in each scene (besides the transform)

I am looking for a way to read the transform of one gameObject and apply it to the other Objects in the other scenes

Comment: Tell me more about what your game is about and I can think of something.

Comment: I am creating a Mixed Reality world in VR. Therefore, I have a 1:1 3d model of my room and the Oculus Quest. I use the VR controllers to align my digital room-model with the real one. Thats why the rooms transform is changed at runtime. Within this room I use hand tracking to interact with buttons on the (real) surface of my room. Thats why I don't want to use DontDestroyOnLoad for the room - my Interfaces need to adapt to the rooms transform. But on the other Hand, I don't want to re-allign the tracking for each sceneLoad.

Comment: I found a solution that works for me: LoadSceneMode.Additive. I simply overlay the scenes and kann acces the transforms this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give alignment as parameter to the DontDestroyOnLoad method, not transform.gameObject.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(alignment.gameObject);
```

Also, you don't need to call this method inside Update(). Just calling it once it enough. You can call it inside Start(), like this:

```
void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(alignment.gameObject);
}
```

Now your alignment gameobject will still be accessible when you change scenes. If you want to access it from other gameobjects in the new scene, you might want to give it a tag or make it a singleton.